# Wpf xamdatagrid DataSource Changed Event

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding, behavior, xamdatagrid

I have a `xamdatagrid` and its `DataSource` binds to a property.
I want to attach a `behavior` to the grid. Each time the DataSource is updated through the property I want do certain things.

I tried to subscribe to different events like `DataContextChanged`, `DataSourceChanged` in the `OnAttached` method but none of these events seems to fire when the property is refreshed.

I have tested a different events like `MouseDoubleClick` it fires fine.

Any clue which event should fire when the `DataSource` is updated through the property ?
Any other suggestions ? Please keep in mind I'm using the `MVVM` pattern.

Thanks

Comment: Still need help  on this one. I have not seen any replies :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation within my project right now and from what I've been able to find the `DataContextChanged` and `DataSourceChanged` events are somewhat ambiguously named. As far as I could find they trigger only when the `DataContext` or `DataSource` as a whole change, i.e. when you pass a new instance of either of those to the `XamDataGrid`.

Unfortunately I've yet to find the right event to fire when the underlying data source (e.g. a collection) changes.